# How can I change uploaded files directory in play 2.0.1?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I tried to specify attachments.path property in my application.conf file, but this had no effects.

In the documentation of play 2.0.1 I didn't find anything explaining how to change uploaded files directory.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

Although there is no such variable in `application.conf` you can easily add it and use in your method. Call it as you wish ie:

new line in `application.conf`:

```
myUploadPath = "/home/your-account/some/custom/upload/folder/"
```

according to the [documentation sample](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaFileUpload):

```
public static Result upload() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    MultipartFormData.FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
    if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType();
        File file = picture.getFile();

        // added lines
        String myUploadPath = Play.application().configuration().getString("myUploadPath");
        file.renameTo(new File(myUploadPath, fileName));

        return ok("file saved as " + myUploadPath + fileName);
    } else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return redirect(routes.Application.uploadform());
    }
}
```

Using this approach you can or even should perform `filename clash` check before renaming, to prevent random overwriting.

Comment: Thank for your response, Marcus, but this did not solve my problem. I have to control the folder in which <picture in your example> reside. However, I solved the problem by starting the app with target/start -Djava.io.tmpdir=<my tmp folder path>

Comment: Oh you didn't specify that you need to control tmp dir :) Thanks for tip, however you can still use my sample to save uploaded file from tmp to exacto location on disk.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't specify it well. But your code could be for sure useful.

Comment: Could you add your comment as answer and mark it as the correct one?