# Playframework - Uploadfile to 2 different folders

Tags: file-upload, directory, playframework-2.0, attachment

just starting at play, and I needed to see it it can be used to do my project.
But after reading some docs, I still can't find a way to put uploaded files in more then one place.

I know that there is the attachments folder, and that I can change it directory in the confs, but what I want is another attachments folder, some thing like:

- If the user upload a photo it would go to /photos folder;
- if the user upload a txt it would go to /docs fodler;

Thanks

--UPDATE--
I'm using Play 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

So after some more research I found this other question:
[How can I change uploaded files directory in play 2.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955424/how-can-i-change-uploaded-files-directory-in-play-2-0-1)

Basically there is no more attachments path configure in this playframework version, so I need to put this manually in the control, just like the answer in that question.